# Add additional recipients to the automated "action required" emails

Tags: azure, azure-alerts

We're working with multiple Azure tenants and subscriptions and want to create a team that stays on top of automated emails from Azure related to service deprecations. Here's a recent example:

> Community support for Node 12 LTS is ending on 30 April 2022 – transition to Node 14 LTS by that date
> You are receiving this email because you may be using a Node 12 app on App Service.

Those are received by default by subscription/resource owners - different people across the tenants/subscriptions. We'd like to have a single email that we'll automate to create a Jira/DevOps ticket for each of those emails and track them.

Can we achieve this with a policy on each subscription? Would it be something on a subscription level or on resource level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific notification you mention is also published through [Azure Service Health](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/service-health-overview). You can [create alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/alerts-activity-log-service-notifications-portal) for your specific needs. In your case, the notification has the type `HealthAdvisory`.

You can create service health alerts on a subscription level and can trigger the usual actions, like webhooks or emails.